# Node.js FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST parsing too many PDF files

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pdf

My script is a pretty simple one: I have a link to a pdf file, I download the file with `request` module and then I'm parsing it to JSON using `pdf2json` module. At the end I store them in the database.

The problem is that I have almost 500 pdf files to download and parse and what I get is a fatal error. Here's the whole message:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  995553 ms: Mark-sweep 1348.6 (1434.6) -> 1345.6 (1434.6) MB, 794.1 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  996352 ms: Mark-sweep 1345.6 (1434.6) -> 1344.8 (1434.6) MB, 799.4 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  997162 ms: Mark-sweep 1344.8 (1434.6) -> 1344.8 (1434.6) MB, 810.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  997969 ms: Mark-sweep 1344.8 (1434.6) -> 1344.6 (1434.6) MB, 806.3 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0000024BFAFC9E79 <JS Object>    
1:charsToGlyphs(akaFont_charsToGlyphs[0000024BFAF04189<undefined>:~13053] 
[pc=000002551914FF4D] (this=00000086B91FE319 <a Font with map 000003EDDCDF64C9>,
chars=000001F2B2EDD0C9 <String[58]: ency liabilities. This may induce spending cuts. 
It also w>)
2: handleText(aka PartialEvaluator_handleText) [0000024BFAF04189 <undefined> :~7176] 
[pc=00000255188CDC3B] (this=000001F2B2E89841 <a...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Does this error appear, becuase the file is too large or maybe because there's some optimization in the code to perform? Or maybe there's another reason...

EDIT:

Here's the file that does the parsing: http://pastebin.com/q1ryuB4Z
And here's where I call the function: http://pastebin.com/fsPMXmwt

Comment: Could you provide a code sample where the `pdf2json` call occurs?

Comment: @SamuelBolduc I've edited the post